# Mean change of dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

After googling around, it looks like there is no straighforward way to do it. Assuming a dataframe with a single column and 1000 rows, how to find average change between each row?

Here is code to generate 1000 rows of random numbers:

```
EL <- runif(1000, min=0, max=1)
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example

Comment: Ok here is code to generate 1000 rows of random numbers : `EL <- runif(1000, min=0, max=1)`

Comment: Would you like to calculate the change between subsequent rows, or all possible combinations? And then the average of those changes.

Comment: `EL` is not a data.frame.

Comment: subsequent, and then average

Comment: How about `(EL[-1]+EL[-length(EL)])/2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use library `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

EL <- data.frame(el = runif(1000, min=0, max=1) )

EL %>%
  mutate(le.diff = el - lag(el)) %>%   # here you calculate the difference
  summarise(le.mean = mean(le.diff, na.rm=T), # here you summarise the difference
        le.sd = sd(le.diff, na.rm=T))

   le.mean     le.sd
1 0.0002199931 0.4089011
```